# How to parse a nested map using GSON

Tags: json, types, dictionary, gson

I'm trying to parse a JSON string with the following format:

```
  { 
      "request" : { 
          "Format" : "json",
          "Method" : "method",
          "NetworkId" : "net",
          "NetworkToken" : "token",
          "Service" : "service",
          "Target" : "target",
          "Version" : "2"
      },
      "response" : { 
          "data" : { 
              "1315" : { 
                  "AffiliateUser" : { 
                      "id" : "1315" 
                  } 
              } 
          },
          "errorMessage" : null,
          "errors" : [  ],
          "httpStatus" : 200,
          "status" : 1
      }
}
```

With this code:

```
public class AffiliateIdResponse{
    private Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>> data;

    public static AffiliateIdResponse fromJson(String jsonString) {
        Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>>() {
        }.getType();
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(mapType, new Gson().getAdapter(TypeToken.get(mapType)));
        return gsonBuilder.create().fromJson(jsonString, AffiliateIdResponse.class);
    }

    public static AffiliateIdResponse handleResponse(MyHttpResponse httpResponse) {
        AffiliateIdResponse response = null;
        if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == MyHttpStatus.OK
                || httpResponse.getStatusCode() == MyHttpStatus.ACCEPTED
                || httpResponse.getStatusCode() == MyHttpStatus.CREATED) {
            response = fromJson(httpResponse.getBody());
        } else {
        response = new AffiliateIdResponse();
        }
        response.setHttpResponseData(httpResponse);
        return response;
    }
}
```

but that field named data is always null. If I instead do something like this:

```
public class AffiliateIdResponse{
    public static AffiliateIdResponse fromJson(String jsonString) {
        Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>>() {
        }.getType();
        Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>> map = null;
        map = new Gson().fromJson("{ \"data\": { \"1315\": { \"AffiliateUser\": {" +
                    "\"id\":\"1315\"}}}}", mapType);
    }

    public static AffiliateIdResponse handleResponse(MyHttpResponse httpResponse) {
        AffiliateIdResponse response = null;
        if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == MyHttpStatus.OK
                || httpResponse.getStatusCode() == MyHttpStatus.ACCEPTED
                || httpResponse.getStatusCode() == MyHttpStatus.CREATED) {
            response = fromJson(httpResponse.getBody());
        } else {
        response = new AffiliateIdResponse();
        }
        response.setHttpResponseData(httpResponse);
        return response;
    }
}
```

the value named map will actually contain the data I want. Why doesn't this work when using the first approach?

Comment: can you share with us the AffiliateIdResponse object?

Comment: @Leo I don't think it will matter since the json parsing is done in the fromJson method, but I've updated to include the whole class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example you have reduced the "visibility" of the deserialization to the 4 tiers of data represented by

1. data
2. 1315
3. AffiliateUser
4. id

thus, the deserialization process maps each tier as a key into a key-value pair with value being the next tier mapping. Your output logged to console appears as

```
{data={1315={AffiliateUser={id=1315}}}}
```

In your first example, there is no indication of the level of visibility into the json you are trying to parse, so I've assumed you are passing in the entire string. As such, you haven't "told" the deserialization process how to "step" through the structure with your implementation.

If you are passing in the entire json structure, then the following will extract the information

```
class ResponseContainer {

    private Response response;

    class Response {
         private Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> data;
         private Integer status;

         public String toString(){
          return "{data : " + data.toString() +"}, status: " + status + "}";
         }
    }

    public ResponseContainer fromJson(String jsonString) {
        new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, ResponseContainer.class);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

Output: `{data : {1315={AffiliateUser={id=1315}}}}, status: 1}`

If this is part of custom deserialization chain where the `jsonString` parameter is a subsequence of the larger data structure, then the "why" is most likely due to a misalignment of the deserialization process -> structure relationship.

Comment: the value jsonString passed into fromJson in the first code block does contain the entire json response. I have done this same thing in another response class where data is just a boolean and I was able to parse that fine. Maybe that's not correct but I would think that same process would work with the data object here.

Comment: I thought that the `typeAdapter` shouldn't be necessary using the approach I've taken. Taking a second look the default map handler will parse out the data with a simple `new Gson().fromJson()`. In most cases, the default deserialization behavior is sufficient.

Comment: Okay so I used this approach and I am able to extract the nested map of the data object. I'm still not sure why the other response class just has a boolean data field and it's parsing that data value correctly but it wont when its a map.

Comment: FYI: The type adapter isn't necessary, I wrote it just like you did.

Comment: So I found out that my structure never worked and that I always needed to parse out the "response" part. Since I was using a boolean it always defaulted to false.